# Algebraic proof of combinatorial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{n-r}=\binom{3n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to obtain the algebraic proof for the following identity. I already know the combinatorial proof but the algebraic proof is evading me.

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{n-r}=\binom{3n}{n}$$

Thanks.

Comment: See also: [2 way counting problem with combinations and series: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}{2n \choose i} = {3n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We make use of the Binomial Theorem. Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{3n} \binom{3n}{k}x^k &= (1+x)^{3n} \\
&= (1+x)^n(1+x)^{2n} \\
&= \left[ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}x^i \right] \left[ \sum_{j=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{j}x^j \right]  \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{3n} \left[\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{k-r}\right]x^k \\
\end{align*}

Hence, by setting $k=n$, we compare the coefficients of $x^n$ of both sides to obtain:
$$
\binom{3n}{n} = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{n-r}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Good. The i in the last x^i term in line 3 should be j.

Comment: Also, how did you get from line 3 to line 4? (The lines with the complicated notation)

Comment: Recall how we multiply polynomials together. That is, if $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^M a_ix^i$ and if $g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^N b_jx^j$, then the degree of their product will be $M+N$ and the coefficient of each $x^k$ is obtained by summing over the products of the coefficients of $x^i$ and $x^j$ such that $i+j=k$. In other words:
$$
f(x)g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{M+N} \left[ \sum_{r=0}^M a_rb_{k-r} \right]x^k
$$

Comment: Apologies for the typos. They've been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Calculate by two ways the coefficient of the term $x^n$ of  $(1+x)^n(1+x)^{2n}$ .