# 2 way counting problem with combinations and series: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}{2n \choose i} = {3n \choose n}$

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Prove that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}{2n \choose i} = {3n \choose n}$$

Comment: See also: [Algebraic proof of combinatorial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{n-r}=\binom{3n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/479642)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a group of $3n$ kids, $n$ boys and $2n$ girls. We want to choose $n$ kids. This can be done in $\binom{3n}{n}$ ways.

Let us count another way. We could choose $0$ girls and $n-0$ boys, or $1$ girl and $n-1$ boys, or $2$ girls and $n-2$ boys, and so on up to $n$ girls and $n-n$ boys. Thus
$$\binom{3n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}.$$
Since $\binom{n}{n-i}=\binom{n}{i}$, this gives our identity.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$
(1+x)^{3n} = (1+x)^n(1+x)^{2n}
$$
and use a [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) for the right hand side

Comment: I'm not sure I see it, I understand the coefficient of $x^n$ in both sides has to be 3n, but I don't understand Cauchy Products, does the counter of the series change or something?

Comment: Just think about what terms from $(1+x)^n$ and $(1+x)^{2n}$ can combine to give you the term $x^n$.