# Use combinatorial argument to prove the following identites:

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

a) $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \binom{2n}{n-i} = \binom{3n}{n}$

b) $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \binom{2n}{n+1} + 2 \binom{2n}{n} + \binom{2n}{n-1}$

c) $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{k+i}{k} = \binom{k+n+1}{k+1}$

I am very confused and have no idea how to approach these problems?
Any assistance?

Comment: do you know any examples of combinatorial arguments that you can draw from?

Comment: For the first one you can have a look, for example, at: [2 way counting problem with combinations and series: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}{2n \choose i} = {3n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513105) or [Algebraic proof of combinatorial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{2n}{n-r}=\binom{3n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/479642).

Answer (score 1):

For $a)$, it is equivalent to 1) select $n$ out of $3n$ elements, and 2) to select $i$ out of the first $n$ elements and then $n-i$ out of the remaining $2n$ elements, for some $i$. That is, each selection done according to 1) can be done according to 2), and vice versa. Thus there are equally many ways to do each, hence the equality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dream up descriptive committee-building stories.

In part a, you have $3n$ people: $n$ of them wear hats to work and $2n$ of them don't. You want to form any committee of size $n$ from among all $3n$ people.

The righthand side counts the number of ways to do this: gather all $3n$ people into a room and choose $n$ of them.

The lefthand side counts the same thing, but in a different way. First, choose exactly $i$ of the hat-wearing people, which can be done in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways. Now you need an additional $n-i$ people from your committee chosen from those without hats, which can be chosen in $\binom{2n}{n-i}$ ways. Summing over $i$ gives you the result.